Parameter value in bias instability modeling
In IMU error modeling, bias instability/flicker noise is often modeled by a first order Gauss-Markov process whose standard deviation is equal to the given BI coefficient [1, p.185][2, p.31]. Because BI is specified by one parameter and GM1 is specified by two parameters, I have a question about the parameter choice in the GM1 equivalent of a BI.
Let $x$ be the GM1 process representing BI and $T$ be the sampling interval
\begin{equation}
    x_k = e^{-T/\tau}x_{k-1} + w_k
\end{equation}
with a process noise
\begin{equation}
    w_k \sim \mathcal{N}(0, Q)
\end{equation}
then the variance of the process is [3, p.280]
\begin{equation}
    \sigma_x^2 = \frac{Q}{1-e^{-2T/\tau}}
\end{equation}
This variance is equal to the variance of BI, which is the square of BI coefficient. Therefore, for the same BI coefficient, there are many combinations of $Q$ and $\tau$ satisfying the equivalence. However, I cannot find any guidance in the literature about picking a value for $\tau$, so I randomly specify $\tau = 1 $hr and obtain the corresponding Q. If you can shed light on this matter I will appreciate it very much.
References
[1] Teodori, Gilles and Neuner, Hans. "Investigation of the trade-off between the complexity of the accelerometer bias model and the state estimation accuracy in INS/GNSS integration" Journal of Applied Geodesy, vol. 17, no. 3, 2023, pp. 181-195.
[2] Ünsal, Derya. Estimation of Deterministic and Stochastic IMU
Error Parameters, dissertation, 2012.
[3] Grewal, Mohinder S. et al. Global Positioning Systems, Inertial Navigation, and Integration, Wiley, 2007.

Please edit your question to cite at least one source on this practice, preferably online and not behind a paywall.
